# Is it possible to localize the push notification text in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, localization, push-notification, windows-phone, windows-8.1

The push notification of my service contains a text that I want to be localized based on the language of the operating system. In iOS the notification center/system has a mechanism with which if an argument in the notification is a key it searches the localised key-value resources in the OS (saved by the app) and translates the notification in the respective language. Is there something similar in Windows Phone or a adequate solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to localize notifications and combobox in Windows store app? (C#/XAML, Multilingual App Toolkit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516939/how-to-localize-notifications-and-combobox-in-windows-store-app-c-xaml-multi)

Answer (score 4):

You can include the localized strings in your app's resource.resw files and reference them in the notification by the ms-resource syntax:

```
 <text id="1">ms-resource:greeting</text>
```

This will replace the text with the greeting value from the resource files.

See [Globalization and accessibility for tile and toast notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh831183.aspx) for more details.

Comment: And is it possible to do this plus add additional text from the payload?